# What should we do with these update and upgrade tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We seem to have four tags about updating and upgrading:

[update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update)

> To update is to "make (something) more modern or up to date." This question should pertain to how to update the Pi's OS's, programming languages, and applications (both native and external.)

[dist-upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dist-upgrade)

> Should be used for questions regarding upgrading a major distribution change. Example: Wheezy to Jessie.

[rpi-update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpi-update)

> a tool to update the firmware of the Raspberry Pi.

[upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) (no tag wiki)

---

It seems that the difference between some of these (in particular [upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade)) is a bit unclear. I'm not entire sure what the difference is, so I can't make any suggestions as to what we need to do.

Do we need to do some tag cleanups or create some synonyms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out.  Since actually merging tags is a moderator-only activity, I made what I felt were appropriate decisions:

- Merged [upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) into [update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update), and made the latter a synonym for the former.
- The (now former) tag blurb for `dist-upgrade` (quoted in your question) makes it pretty clear this is about the `apt-get dist-upgrade` command.  However, while it does describe a major use case for that command, it might be construed as misleading in relation to what `man apt-get` actually says about `dist-upgrade`.  Further, since `apt-get` is in the process of being depreciated in favour of an integrated `apt` command, I'm not sure what the future is for `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and there were only 3 questions with this tag, one of which also has [update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) on it.

  So I merged [dist-upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dist-upgrade) into [update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) as well and expanded the wiki for the latter to hopefully dampen any confusion.  I also made it a synonym; the purpose of doing so in this case is to prevent someone down the line from re-creating a "dist-upgrade" tag -- attempting to do so will invoke the synonym and add [update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update), which is more reasonably scoped.
- Since `rpi-update` is a specific tool, I clarified the blurb and wiki a bit and otherwise left it as is.